# My form is not allowing my result to be displayed on click

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have created a simple Grade calculator and I am just working on little things now. One is not allowing the user to not enter an input into the input box. A possible solution to this is to include the html5 required attribute. To use this I had to put my code into a form going by the W3Schools example here.
[HTML  required Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_required.asp).

Before implementing this into my code it worked fine and it displayed the result on screen. I just want to know why the form is not allowing my results to display on screen.

```
My code
```

```js
    var Result;
    var Worth;
    var caPercentage;
    var gradeWanted;
    var examPercentage;
    var gradeWorth;
    var marksNeeded;

    //Calculates the Continous Assessment result based on users inputs 
    function calcCaPercentage() {
  
   //result equals the users Continous Assesment results input value
 Result = parseFloat(document.getElementById("caResult").value);
  
   //result equals over Continous Assesment Worth input value
 Worth = parseFloat(document.getElementById("caWorth").value);
 
 caPercentage = Worth * (Result / 100);
  
   //CA Percentage result gets displayed here
 document.getElementById("caPercentage").innerHTML = caPercentage + "%";
  
   //Returns the Continous Assessment Precentage for the other methods
 return caPercentage;
    }

    //Calcualtes the users exam percentage needed to get the grade they want
    function calcExamPercentage() {

   //GradeWanted equals the grade the user wants     
 gradeWanted = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gradeWanted").value);
  
   //x equals the Continous Assessment Precentage from the calcCaPercentage 
    function calcExamPercentage(){

 var x = calcCaPercentage();
 examPercentage = gradeWanted - x;
  
   //Exam Percentage gets displayed here
 document.getElementById("examPercentage").innerHTML = examPercentage +"%";
  
   //Returns the Exam Precentage for the other methods
 return examPercentage;
    }

    //Calculates the Marks needed for the user to get the grade they want
    function calcMarkNeeded() {

   //gradeWorth equals what the overall Exam worth input
 gradeWorth = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gradeWorth").value);
  
   //y equals the Exam Precentage from the calcExamPercentage function
 var y = calcExamPercentage();
  
   //marksNeeded equals a round up version of the overall result
 marksNeeded = Math.floor((y / gradeWorth) * 100 /1);

   //The marks needed will be displayed here
 document.getElementById("marksNeeded").innerHTML = marksNeeded + " Marks!";
    }
```

```html
 <form>
  <div class="container">
  
   <div class="box boxInput1">

    <h4>Calculate your CA Percentage</h4>

    <p>Enter your CA Result: <input type="text" class="inputBox" placeholder="Enter you CA Result here.." id="caResult" required></p>
    

    <p>Enter overall CA mark: <input type="text" class="inputBox" placeholder="Enter what the CA is worth here.." id="caWorth" required></p>

    <!--
    <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="calcCaPercentage()"> 
    <input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="calcCaPercentage()"> 
    -->

   </div>
   
   <div class="box boxResult boxInput1">
    <p><br>Your CA percentage is: <br><br><span id="caPercentage"></span></p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="box ">

    <h4>Calculate the percentage needed to pass the exam!</h4>

    <p>Enter the Grade you are aiming to achieve: <input type="text" class="inputBox" placeholder="Enter the Grade you want to get here.." id="gradeWanted" required></p>

    <!-- 
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="calcExamPercentage()">Calculate</button> 
    <input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="calcExamPercentage()">
    -->
   </div>
   
   <div class="box boxResult">
    <p><br>Percentage you need to pass the exam is: <br><br><span id="examPercentage"></span></p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="box">

    <h4>Calculate the marks needed to pass the exam!</h4>

    <p>Enter what your exam is worth overall: <br> <input type="text" class="inputBox" placeholder="Enter what the exam is worth here.." id="gradeWorth"></p>

    <input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="calcMarkNeeded()" required>
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn"  onclick="calcMarkNeeded()">Calculate</button> -->

   </div>
   
   <div class="box boxResult">
    <p><br>You Need <br><br><span id="marksNeeded"></span></p>
   </div>
  
  </div>
   
 </form>
```

Here is a link to my code working in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mono92/pen/rqBaNK)

Is this a drawback to using forms ?

Comment: submit buttons submit forms. cancel the default submit action.

Comment: Okay the reason I used input was due to the required functionality not working using a button, what should I change it too ?

Comment: you miss a close parenthesis in one of your function. proper indenting would display the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `<input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="calcMarkNeeded()" required>` into `<input type="button" class="btn" onclick="calcMarkNeeded()">` or `<button class="btn" onclick=calcMarkNeeded()">Calculate</button>`.

Submit buttons will submit the form to whatever ( server ) action the form defines.
But there's no server listening for your submit, so your website will just load an empty page instead of the form submit response. And an empty page does not contain the output div you're trying to write the result to.

So never use `<input type="submit">` unless you actually want to submit a form.
There's `<input type="button">` and even a `<button></button>` element to use instead.

Also, using the required attribute on a button doesn't do anything. Buttons are to be pressed, not submitted. You can't "force" a user to press the button by using required, like you can "force" a user to fill in a particular input.

Comment: Okay Thank you for this and for explaning. Makes sense once you spell it out like that. Okay in regards to the required part, what would you suggest? I just need the user to fill out all inputs otherwise the output will be NaN. Would something like autofocus work ? Sorry if this sounds simple I'm still learning.

Comment: Just keep the required attribute on the actual text inputs, they work on those. I mentioned this because I didn't exactly understand your comment: `the reason I used input was due to the required functionality not working using a button`. Putting required on a button input is useless, but Do keep required on the text field inputs.

Comment: Okay Thanks I appreciate the help.